# Work with iOS 7 top layout guide

Tags: ios, storyboard, uinavigationbar, autolayout

I'm designing a view controller in my storyboard. It contains a navigation bar at the top and a content view. I've set the constraints as

- Navigation bar's top space to top layout guide = 0
- Content view fills the remaining space (leading and trailing space to superview = 0 ; bottom space to superview = 0, top space to navigation bar =0)

Because I want to display the status bar, I'm using the top layout guide to make the navigation bar displayed just under it. It works with a standard UINavigationBar. 
But I have custom navigation bar : I've created my own class inheriting UINavigationBar.

The problem is : when specifying this custom class for the navigation bar in the Identity Inspector of the interface builder, the bar is not at the right place when running the app.

Is there anything to add or modify in `initWitFrame` or `initWithCoder`, or something else to do, so my custom navigation bar will follow the constraints of my storyboard.

**EDIT** - source added

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // additional setup
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // same setup than initWithFrame:
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    //[self setFrame:rect]; navigation bar is not at the right place if uncommented
}
```

Comment: If found that function `drawRect:`is automatically trigged, setting my navigation bar origin to (0,0). If y don't override it, I'm loosing some custom settings of my bar, especially the background color. Any clue?

Comment: Is it working, when you don't overwrite `drawRect:`? Can you show the source of your custom `UINavigationBar`?

Comment: Yes, it is working when don't override `drawRect:`. But I'm loosing some point of the customization. I edit my post for source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you calling `[self setFrame:rect];`? `frame` is correctly set up at this point, you shouldn't change it. Also, `rect` is in an internal coordinate system of the navigation bar.

Comment: OK, thanks for your explanations. But why do I need to override `drawRect:` and do nothing in it, otherwise my navigation bar does not look as it was defined in `initWithCoder:` ?

Comment: @zbMax: What code do you have in here: `// additional setup`? You shouldn't overwrite `drawRect:` if you're not doing anything in it. I've assumed that you've also skipped some code in there.

Comment: @zbMax: you might also want to read the section "Defining a Custom View" in [View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW23).

Comment: In my `//additional setup`, I'm just setting the background image, and adding customized buttons. I've follow the section you've mention. I was not setting the autoresizingMask. But even with this modification, not overriding `drawRect:` make me loose my background image.

Comment: @zbMax: can you separate the code that's not working into a new project and share it for example on Dropbox? Because right now I'm not sure what's wrong with it.

Comment: @zbMax: I've seen the project. Can you explain again what's wrong with the navigation bar's position?

Comment: In my storyboard, on some views, I set the navigation bar to be of "myNavBar" class. The problem is if I don't override the "drawRect:" method, I'm loosing the background image of my navBar. And in my case, I'm not doing anything in this method.

Comment: @zbMax: You can set the background image with `[self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"fd_entete.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];` (put it in `initWithCoder:`). Now you don't need to override `drawRect:`. You're also using `menuBorder` layer, but I'm not sure what it does.

Comment: As iOS 7 doesn't provide borders for buttons, I'm drawing them with `CALayer`. Thanks to your help, I don't have anymore to override `drawRect:`. Thanks a lot.